# Prospect of pursuing online degree in my off-shift hours with new job which has flexible work hours, how to approach to discuss this with management?

Tags: communication, career-development, india, work-life-balance

I am trying to pursue an online degree which may help me plan future prospects of my career but I have to do a tech job alongside to afford the course. The problem is the company work hours are standard 9:00 to 5:00 but employees can be asked to extend as and when deemed necessary at their discretion. Consulted with the friends working in the org and found that extension of work hours is very common and duration may extend to about total 10 to 12 hrs. This can affect the time which I would be able to properly dedicate to the course. So how should I proceed to negotiate the working hours ? Looking for some pointers, some catches etc which could put me in better negotiating position. I have a few years of experience in the tech and the course may or may not help in the company objective.

Comment: Country of Employment is India

Comment: Some sort of guarantee that you won't have to work more than 9 to 5 ? - Yes.
Are you currently an employee of this company? - cleared my rounds, final discussion on plate.

Comment: Did you know that beforehand or did it come up during the interview? This is a HUGE red flag imo. Though I dont know about work culture in india, so it might be normal for you? In my experience when a company tells you in advance you might have to work 12 hours (possibly unpaid?), it is usually worse than the tell you. Wouldnt trust that they will help you with your course or give you the time. You could of course just go when work time is officially over (if indian laws apply?). But then dont expect to stay long at this company.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to talk to your manager and let them know that you intend to pursue such a course. Depending on the size and culture of organization, this may be appreciated, or may be discouraged.

In case your organization has formal policies for employee education alongside work, you will be able to find necessary resources on your internal portals, and can expect required support from the manager. Some organizations even pay upto certain local limits for employees to gain such education, so do look into those.

In case you work at a smaller startup / not so employee centric organization, the best you should expect is an informal understanding from the manager to support you in your endeavor. Needless to say, go for a program where you've the option of watching recorded lectures, to avoid any lags.

That said, as long as what you are studying is work related, I've seen most managers in organizations that I've worked at in India are willing to give the required leeway to pursue such courses. It goes without saying though that they would expect your work performance to not be impacted in any way by this.